# htaccess to check if user is logged in

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cookies

I want to prevent users from seeing some of my assets unless they are logged in.  Currently I can do this when I embed them into a page with code but if someone direct links to say a pdf they can see it if they are not logged in.

I am thinking htaccess may be the best approach.  Something like set a cookie when they login and check if that cookie exists but it doesn't seem to be working.  I set this as I don't have a cookie with that value but it still shows me the pdf.  Note sure if my htaccess code is wrong or if it is just not possible.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !UserAccess=123 [NC]
RewriteRule ^.pdf$ / [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  In the long run I will move all assets outside of public directory and embed them but looking for a quick fix in the time being.

Thanks

Comment: put the files outside of php root and get/show/download them (if allowed) via php. You cannot (well, not that I know) achieve this via htaccess. Yes, you could have a subdirectory [only accessable with credentials](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/) - but not via cookie. more links: https://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Comment: `^.pdf$` means to match `.pdf` so your rule is applied only when the uri is exactly `/.pdf` .Remove the carat `^` from the beginning of your pattern .